# Browsermob Proxy (java): failing to rewrite a URL

Tags: java, url-rewriting, browsermob-proxy

I'm using BrowserMob Proxy and I want to redirect traffic from my production server to a test server. For that I'm using a `rewriteUrl` in the followin manner:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BrowserMobProxyServer server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        server.setTrustAllServers(true);

        server.start(8888);
        server.rewriteUrl("(https?://)init.mycompany.com(.*)","$1platform-sandbox.mycompany.com$2//");

        if (server.isStarted()) {
            System.out.println("Server started on " + server.getClientBindAddress() + ":" + server.getPort());
        }

        server.addRequestFilter(new RequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public HttpResponse filterRequest(io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpMessageContents httpMessageContents, HttpMessageInfo httpMessageInfo) {
                System.out.println("REQUEST");
                System.out.println("Original: " + httpMessageInfo.getOriginalUrl());
                System.out.println("Current: " + httpMessageInfo.getUrl());
                return null;
            }
        });

        server.addResponseFilter(new ResponseFilter() {
            @Override
            public void filterResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpMessageContents httpMessageContents, HttpMessageInfo httpMessageInfo) {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE");
                System.out.println("Original: " + httpMessageInfo.getOriginalUrl());
                System.out.println("Current: " + httpMessageInfo.getUrl());
                if (httpMessageInfo.getOriginalUrl() != httpMessageInfo.getUrl()) {
                    System.out.printf("DIFFERENT!!!!");
                }
            }
        });

        server.newHar("test");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I have a partial success:

1. The two `//` symbols are added in the end (did that for testing).
2. However, `init` is not replaced by `platform-sandbox`

REQUEST

Original: https://init.mycompany.com

Current: https://init.mycompany.com

REQUEST

Original: https://init.mycompany.com/sdk/v6.4.6?applicationKey=42a8c1f5

Current: https://init.mycompany.com/sdk/v6.4.6?applicationKey=42a8c1f5

RESPONSE

Original: https://init.mycompany.com/sdk/v6.4.6?applicationKey=42a8c1f5

Current: https://init.mycompany.com/sdk/v6.4.6?applicationKey=42a8c1f5//

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with http requests and it works good (`init` is replaced with `platform-sandbox`).

The problem appears only in case of https requests.
When you request https URL the request method `CONNECT` is used to establish a tunnel connection. Currently the Browsermob Proxy doesn't support rewriting of URLs if request method is `CONNECT`.

There are more details in the source code. You can set breakpoint on [this line in the code](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/browsermob-proxy-2.1.1/browsermob-core/src/main/java/net/lightbody/bmp/filters/RewriteUrlFilter.java#L47) and debug http and https traffic through this point to see the difference. 
In case of https traffic when request method `CONNECT` is used the RewriteUrlFilter returns null and rewriting rules are not applied to such requests.